# Unity what's wrong with my instantiating algorithm?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I dont know if I can call this algorithm. But I am working on a game in which player will move in a circular path. [image: my project image]

As you can see in the picture player is suppose to orbit the circle. And obstacle shall be instantiated in the circle.I am trying to first create the obstacle in first half(left to the long cube) and then in the second half. But things are getting created in the next half too when code is not supposed to do that. Also, it is showing argument exception error. Please have a look at my code and tell me whether my method is wrong or my formulas are wrong or anything else.

```
   public class ObjectInstantiater : MonoBehaviour {
    DataHolder dataholder;
    GameObject Obstacle;
    LevelData leveldata;

    private int currentlevel=0; // default level starts from 0
    private List<GameObject> Inactivegameobject = new List<GameObject>(); // this object can be used
    private List<GameObject> Activegameobject = new List<GameObject>();

    private int totalgameobjects;
    private int firsthalfgameobjects, secondhalfgameobjects;
    public float outerradius;
    public float innerradius;

    private bool shallspawnouterradiues = true;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {
        dataholder = (Object)GameObject.FindObjectOfType<DataHolder>() as DataHolder;
        Obstacle = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cylinder);
        leveldata = dataholder.Leveldata[0];
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Updateleveldata();
        FirstHalf();
    }
    public int Currentlevel
    {
        get { return currentlevel; }
        set { currentlevel = value;
            leveldata = dataholder.Leveldata[currentlevel];//sets the level data
        }
    }

    private void Updateleveldata() // this function gets called after a round
    {
        totalgameobjects = Random.Range(leveldata.MinimumObstacle, leveldata.MaximumObstacle);
        firsthalfgameobjects = Mathf.RoundToInt(totalgameobjects / 2);
        secondhalfgameobjects = totalgameobjects - firsthalfgameobjects;

    }
    private void FirstHalf()
    {
        Debug.Log(firsthalfgameobjects);
        Vector3 pos;
        if (Inactivegameobject.Count < firsthalfgameobjects)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= (firsthalfgameobjects - Inactivegameobject.Count); x++)
            {
                GameObject obs = Instantiate(Obstacle) as GameObject;
                obs.SetActive(false);
                Inactivegameobject.Add(obs);
            }
        }
        float spawnangledivision = 180 / firsthalfgameobjects;
        float spawnangle = 180f;
        for(int x = 0; x < firsthalfgameobjects; x++)
        {
            float proceduralRandomangle = spawnangle;
             proceduralRandomangle = Random.Range(proceduralRandomangle , proceduralRandomangle + 2f);
            if (shallspawnouterradiues)
            {
                 pos = new Vector3(outerradius * Mathf.Cos(spawnangle), outerradius * Mathf.Sin(spawnangle), 0f);
                shallspawnouterradiues = false;
            }else
            {
                 pos = new Vector3(innerradius * Mathf.Cos(spawnangle), innerradius * Mathf.Sin(spawnangle), 0f);
                shallspawnouterradiues = true;
            }
            spawnangle += spawnangledivision;
            Inactivegameobject[0].SetActive(true); // set it to 0 
            Inactivegameobject[0].transform.position = pos;
            Activegameobject.Add(Inactivegameobject[0]);
            Inactivegameobject.RemoveAt(0);
        }

    }

    private void SecondHalf()// No need to check this
    {
        if (Inactivegameobject.Count < firsthalfgameobjects)
        {
            GameObject obs = Instantiate(Obstacle) as GameObject;
            obs.SetActive(false);
            Inactivegameobject.Add(obs);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you add a debug log to `SecondHalf()` to make sure that the things are instantiated from the `SecondHalf()` function?

Comment: @EmreE I am sorry I did not explain the problem properly. The problem is FirstHalf() function is instantiating in both places. SecondHalf() is not called from anywhere

Comment: So if the origin of the green circle is origin (0,0), Your instantiated gameObject's x value needs to be less than 0 in order to be on the left side. Thats where your **pos** and **spawnangle** comes in. Your `Mathf.Cos(spawnangle)` needs to be negative. For that your angle needs to be between 180-360. But `float spawnangle = 180 / firsthalfgameobjects;` seems like out of this scope. Try giving 180-360 degree as your **spawnangle** and see the results.

Comment: @EmreE Ok I did make the change in my code. But still out of luck. And also can you tell me why it is showing argument exception error

Comment: I do not know anything about the error. If you double click it, will it open something in your code? I am not sure. And for the calcuations, if i got your formula correct. When x is negative your objects will instantiate on the left side. (Assuming the origin)

Comment: Cos is negative between Cos(90) and Cos(270) In degrees. What i've said was 180-360 this was wrong. Can you also try with those values 90-270. I've used [this calculator](http://www.rapidtables.com/calc/math/Cos_Calculator.htm)

Comment: @EmreE This time you got your formula correct. Thanks. But argument exception error causing problem

Comment: @EmreE I also found when the value if more than 3 one cylinder is being instantiated in centre

Comment: @EmreE Also nothing opens when I click on that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156155/discussion-between-emree-and-samrat-luitel).